# How do i add no increment to my primary key?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to add auto_increment to an existing column but the modify isn't working and i don't know why, i have this.

```
ALTER TABLE Pedidos
MODIFY ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

ID is already not null primary key

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: You forgot word `COLUMN` after `MODIFY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE Pedidos(
 MODIFY COLUMN ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```